# How to fetch CloudFlare API dictionary in Paython

Tags: python, dictionary, curl

I was browsing around for 1 day already, but I was not able to find how to fetch CloudFlare API responses in Python.

Usually the communication between the host and the CloudFlare's servers is established using cURL:

```
curl -k -s "https://api.cloudflare.com/host-gw.html" -d 'act=user_lookup' -d 'host_key=8ayf9yaoh2h8faosh2o8dhas' -d 'cloudflare_email=admin@tech-world.info' | python -mjson.tool
```

So this is the cURL request, which returns the following dictionary:

```
{
"msg": null,
"request": {
    "act": "user_lookup",
    "cloudflare_email": "admin@tech-world.info"
},
"response": {
    "cloudflare_email": "admin@tech-world.info",
    "hosted_zones": [
        "tech-world.info"
    ],
    "unique_id": "78yastaig238w9ayfhao8h28hdas",
    "user_api_key": "ga7srgfr2i7dfagsd2r89hasd",
    "user_authed": true,
    "user_exists": true,
    "user_key": "d8ha92hiuhda7892houkljhadskju"
},
"result": "success"
}
```

So I am trying to execute the cURL command from python in order to get the dictionary output (this is just placeholder cURL execution exapmle):

```
import subprocess
my_var = subprocess.call(["curl", "-X", "GET", "-I", "http://www.tech-world.com"])
```

But the call() method prints the data it receives, but I want to assign the dict to variable for later use.

I have checked the urllib2, but I did not find a way to use it to accomplish my goals.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you use cURL instead of normal Python HTTP library (such as [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/))?

```
r = requests.post('https://api.cloudflare.com/host-gw.html', data={'host_key': '8ayf9yaoh2h8faosh2o8dhas', 'cloudflare_email': 'admin@tech-world.info', 'act': 'user_lookup'})
```

Also there is a library named [pyflare](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflare) for working with CloudFlare using Python.

(it's the first text that I post for urgent warning)

I can't comment (too low reputation), but I can't to not alert that's you have opened your credentials from production server.